# How to set VM in Oracle Virtual Box with different IP address outside of Host subnet?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a virtual box VM with WINDOWS 10 running on a Windows 10 host.

The host has IP address: 192.168.40.101
I have devices in 192.168.1.xxx
which I would like the VM to access

So I changed the VM's IP address (in the windows network configuration) to 192.168.1.50 (no IP conflict for sure)

However I still can't access nor ping the devices on the 192.168.1.xxx network

I would love to know the solution to this if anyone can help, thank you!

Comment: Is your VM network adapter set to bridged or NAT?

Comment: kept it Default  = NAT

Comment: Are the 192.168.1.x devices on a different network than the host? Or do you have the subnet mask set to 255.255.0.0 and they're all on the same network?

Comment: the 192.168.1.x  devices are on the same network switch, and the host is set to 255.255.255.0 (i honestly dont know if i should set it otherwise, im not good at advance networking)

Comment: Seems like a weird host IP address then. Why isn't it something like 192.168.1.101? Had you statically set that one? Also for starters, set the VM network adapter to bridged.

Comment: oh, nah because the network is really set to 192.168.40.xxx 
hence the host is set to the same subnet. But there are a few devices (like IP cameras) that are set on the usual 192.168.1.xxx IP ranges, and I needed the VM to access those instead of having to setup an actual PC for this purpose.

Comment: Even if you put your VM on the same subnet, if you're using NAT, it won't matter. NAT uses the host's IP connection.  Simplest solution is to just change you subnet mask from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.192.0 which will put IPs from 192.168.0.x to 192.168.63.x in the same subnet.   Otherwise, you'll need to use bridged mode for the VM for it to act like it's on the same 192.168.1.x subnet.

Comment: @essjae - ok that makes sense. thanks very much man. appreciate it